# MySQL left join with different parameter as group by gives different results

Tags: mysql

Here is the first statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT E.EMP_NAME,O.NAME AS DEPTNAME 
FROM M_EMPLOYEE E 
LEFT JOIN M_USERS U ON U.USER_ID=E.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN M_ORGANIZATION O ON U.DEPT_ID=O.ORG_ID  
GROUP BY E.USER_ID)T WHERE T.EMP_NAME='lm';
```

Here is the result:

---

**EMP_NAME**     |       **DEPTNAME**

---

**lm**                    |          **null**

---

Here is the second statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT E.EMP_NAME,O.NAME AS DEPTNAME 
FROM M_EMPLOYEE E 
LEFT JOIN M_USERS U ON U.USER_ID=E.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN M_ORGANIZATION O ON U.DEPT_ID=O.ORG_ID 
GROUP BY U.USER_ID )T WHERE T.EMP_NAME='lm';
```

Here is the result:

---

**EMP_NAME**     |       **DEPTNAME**

---

**lm**                    |          **qitan**

---

**Question**: Why the two results are different?

Comment: We need the tables structures also. so post that.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of group by is inappropriate and (under certain circumtances) misleading.

Answer (score 1):

From [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding
>   unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful
>   primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in
>   the GROUP BY are the same for each group. **The server is free to
>   choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are indeterminate.**

In your case, you are gouping by `U.USER_ID` and selecting un-aggregated columns `E.EMP_NAME,O.NAME`